# Powershell: Get all suspended tasks

Tags: windows, powershell, server, wmi, get-wmiobject

I am trying to get all the suspended tasks from a terminal server running windows server 2012.

I have tried using powershell with wmi object like so:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName computername -Property status
```

But the `status` property of all the processes is empty, yet it shows up in the details view of the task manager like so:

[image]

I have also tried the following code to try and get the status of the running threads:

```
$processes = Get-Process * -ComputerName ppivts | select name,threads

foreach ($process in $processes)
{
   foreach ($thread in $process.Threads)
   {
       if($thread.ThreadState -ne "Wait"){
           $process.Name
           $thread.ThreadState
       }
   }

}
```

This does not work either. How do I get the status of the process and more specifically the suspended ones?

Comment: @Persistent13 I have looked at that solution and as you can see from the above code that it won't return the suspended or running tasks.  It does not reflect what is seen in the task manager.

Comment: @Persistent13 I apologize, I was able to find the suspend member name in the waitreason enumeration.  So, I should be able to query for that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could improve the latter code snippet as follows:

```
$processes = Get-Process *
$processHt = @{}                                 # empty hash table
foreach ($process in $processes) {
  foreach ($thread in $process.Threads) {   
    if($thread.ThreadState -eq "Wait") {
      if ( $processHt.Containskey( $process.Name ) ) {
        if ( $processHt[$process.Name] -match $($thread.WaitReason.ToString()) ) {
        } else {
          $processHt[$process.Name] += ",$($thread.WaitReason.ToString())"
        }
      } else {
        $processHt.Add( $process.Name , $thread.WaitReason.ToString() )
      }
    }
  }
}

"`n=== all threads suspended ==="
$processHt.Keys | Where-Object { $processHt[$_] -eq 'Suspended' }
"`n=== some thread suspended ==="
$processHt.Keys | Where-Object { $processHt[$_] -match 'Suspended' } | 
  ForEach-Object { @{ $_ = $processHt[$_] } } |
  Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders       # merely for simple output look
```

**Sample output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\46546587.ps1

=== all threads suspended ===
WWAHost

=== some thread suspended ===

System   FreePage,Executive,EventPairLow,Suspended,VirtualMemory,LpcReceive,ExecutionDelay
WWAHost  Suspended                                                                        
explorer UserRequest,Executive,EventPairLow,Suspended                                     



PS D:\PShell>
```

Corresponding Task Manager screenshot:

[image: Corresponding Task Manager screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This Powershell WMI code will work on both local and remote PC

```
    $fname = "csrss.exe"
    $ComputerName = "Server"
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName Win32_Process | where Name -eq $fname |
        Foreach{
            $processHandle = $_.handle
            echo "processHandle=$processHandle"
            $Threads = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_Thread | Where-Object { $_.ProcessHandle -eq $processHandle }
            "The $name process has $($threads.count) threads"
            $threads | Format-Table -Property priority, Handle, ProcessHandle, thread*, ProcessCreation, ClassName, User*Time, kernel*Time
    }
    # ThreadStates:
    #  0 - Initialized. It is recognized by the microkernel.
    #  1 - Ready. It is prepared to run on the next available processor.
    #  2 - Running. It is executing.
    #  3 - Standby. It is about to run. Only one thread may be in this state at a time.
    #  4 - Terminated. It is finished executing.
    #  5 - Waiting. It is not ready for the processor. When ready, it will be rescheduled.
    #  6 - Transition. The thread is waiting for resources other than the processor.
    #  7 - Unknown. The thread state is unknown.
    # ThreadWaitReason:
    #  0 - Executive
    #  1 - FreePage
    #  2 - PageIn
    #  3 - PoolAllocation
    #  4 - ExecutionDelay
    #  5 - FreePage
    #  6 - PageIn
    #  7 - Executive
    #  8 - FreePage
    #  9 - PageIn
    # 10 - PoolAllocation
    # 11 - ExecutionDelay
    # 12 - FreePage
    # 13 - PageIn 
    # 14 - EventPairHigh
    # 15 - EventPairLow
    # 16 - LPCReceive
    # 17 - LPCReply
    # 18 - VirtualMemory
    # 19 - PageOut
    # 20 - Unknown
```